# spark.shuffle.safetyFraction and spark.storage.safetyFraction difference

Tags: memory-management, apache-spark, jvm

I am studying [this article on Apache Spark architecture](http://0x0fff.com/spark-architecture/) for sometime now.

There are two safety fractions as per description:
*spark.shuffle.safetyFraction* and *spark.storage.safetyFraction* which are given as 0.8 and 0.9 of JVM respectively.
Shuffle takes 0.2 of *spark.shuffle.safetyFraction* whereas storage takes 0.6 of *spark.storage.safetyFraction*.
The image given is however misleading.(One of the comments confirms this)

My question is:

How shuffle and storage can take 0.8 and 0.9 of same memory of JVM??
Are they shared? Then, in worst case what happens?

I googled but didn't get any documentation on these.
Any help is appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0):

These configs are for internal use only and not exposed to the public, please refer to [this pull request](https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/2135) .  You can set  `memoryFraction` instead.

Answer (score 0):

JVM heap can be divided into three parts:
Storage, Execution(Shuffle) and Other
Storage：in default 60% of heap size, controlled by spark.storage.memoryfraction(default value:0.6)，while spark.storage.safetyFraction controls the real size we can allocate, which is 0.9 in default, which means we have to reserve 10% to avoid OOM, among the 90% of storage, 20% is used to unroll

Shuffle：20% of heap size by default, controlled by spark.shuffle.memoryfraction, however, for safety reasons, we cannot use all of them, so we introduced another parameter to control it, which is spark.shuffle.safetyFraction, in default it is 0.8.

Other：reserved, 20% of heap size。